# Writting events from kafka to Hive with ORC format

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, hdfs, orc

I am trying to use a kafka connector to writte data in Hive with OCR format from a Kafka bus.

The events in the bus are in avro format. I need somethig like this [ConvertAvroToORC
 for NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hive-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.ConvertAvroToORC/) but with Kafka Connectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been released io.confluent.connect.hdfs.orc.OrcFormat included in the HDFS connector io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/configuration_options.html#hdfs-2-sink-connector-configuration-properties

Answer (score 0):

ORC is not supported with HDFS Kafka Connect currently.

You're welcome to build the PR and try it out on your own.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/294